# Java VisualVM - CPU Sampler - find performance issues

Tags: java, cpu, memory-leaks, visualvm

I have a serious problem with a java application which is eating the cpu with the time. So I installed VisualVM and saw this:

[image]

Something is creating more and more Threads, while the application isn´t used.
Now I would like to know what is causing this. Via. google I could only find tutorials on how to find memory leaks with visualvm but not cpu.

Comment: what do you see on the threads tab?

Comment: go to the threads tab and identify the threads that are created without being finished

Comment: @BevynQ and Frederic Close There are hundreds of npc mgr read/write threads. How does me help this now ?

Comment: That would sound like npc mgr threads are never ending and should be created sparingly. You possible have a process that is createing them when it should not.